# How to Update Model via ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view that is constructed used a ViewModel.

ViewModel:

```
public class StoreEmployee
{
public IEnumerable<Store> Stores { get; set; }
public HechosLiquidador Hechos { get; set; }}
```

**View:**

**The problem:**

What this view makes is a form for each item inside the IEnumerable of Stores, each one with a submit button.

When I submit a form, it goes to the Post Action where I try to **update** the values that are included in this form.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Stores)
{
    <tr>
        <td hidden  >
            <form id="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.StoreID))" asp-action="Management" asp-route-id="@item.StoreID" method="post">
            </form>
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-3">
            <input form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.StoreID))" type="hidden" asp-for="@item.StoreID" />
            <div class="form-group" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.StoreID))">
                <div>
                    <input form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.StoreID))" asp-for="@item.StoreName" name="StoreName" readonly class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@item.StoreName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.StoreID))">
                <div>
                    <select asp-for="@item.Usuario" name="Usuario" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.UserId" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.StoreID))"></select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="@item.Usuario" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.StoreID))">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" asp-for="@item.FechaDesignado" name="FechaDesignado" id="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","ownID",item.StoreID))" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.StoreID))" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@item.FechaDesignado" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.StoreID))">
                    <div>
                        <select name="Status" asp-for="@item.IncomePeriodicity" class="form-control" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.StoreID))">
                            <option value="0">Diario</option>
                            <option value="1">Semanal</option>
                            <option value="2">Mensual</option>
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.IncomePeriodicity" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-1">
                <input form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.StoreID))" id="submit-data" type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
        </td>
    </tr>}
```

Here, in the **Post action method**, I don't know how to update the values using TryUpdateModelAsync:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Management")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Management(int? id, StoreEmployee StoreEmployee)
{
    var storetoupdate = _context.Stores.SingleOrDefault(m => m.StoreID == id.Value);

    if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(
        storetoupdate,
        "",
        s => s.Usuario, s => s.IncomePeriodicity, s => s.FechaDesignado))
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Management");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Management");
}
```

I've read that I must add a prefix on this part:

```
        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(
        storetoupdate,
        "Store",
        s => s.Usuario, s => s.IncomePeriodicity, s => s.FechaDesignado))
```

Adding the name of the model it is related inside the ViewModel, but is not saving the changes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your view makes no sense and your creating form controls that have no relationship to your model. See the dupe on your previous question. You model is for a collection so you need one form and submit all items in one action. Having multiple forms makes not sense (you can only submit one form at a time)

Comment: And if you want to edit only one item then display a readonly list of the collection and have an edit link for each that either redirects to an edit page for that item, or displays a modal form on the page

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hello, I'm submitting only one form at the time. each iteration creates a form with the object properties and it's respective submit button, and it repeats creating N forms and N submit buttons for each one.

Comment: Again, that makes no sense. Why would you degrade performance by generate all that extra html that is never used. And its a confusing UI - a user might edit controls in the 2 or 3 forms and click a submit button on another and nothing will be submitted. Your form needs to be based on your model which it currently is not

Comment: It's an attemp to construct and editable grid. Not all the solutions must be constructed the same way, I understand your point and I take it into consideration but this is where I'm right now and this is the doubt.

Comment: Then have one form and submit all the changes in one action (see the dupe on your previous question)

Comment: Sincerely, I don't believe I won't get an answer to the specific situation exposed here after all these comments. I already have a form being submited, the problem is in the post action. The link you posted on the other question couldn't help me very much (this is a case of an update) but I got some aditional information online (http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/17/asp-net-mvc-using-controller-updatemodel-when-using-a-viewmodel/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151656/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-luis-alberto-delgado-de-la-flo).